# Disable selection in text input

Tags: angularjs

Basic problem is, when user tabs in a specific text input on a form, prefilled "+36" gets selected. I'd like to somehow put the cursor right after it (after the +36), instead of selecting the whole word. I've been thinking about disabling text selection of text inputs but no result yet. Googled a lot for it but couldnt find anything but disabling text selection on web pages, which is not really related. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Create a label with text `+36` before the input.

Comment: @Satpal could be a perfect solution if it was me to decide about sitebuild but this is not the case now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jquery, you can try something like this on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").focus(function() {
      var input = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
          input.selectionStart = input.selectionEnd;
      }, 1);
  });
});
```

Please find the Jsfiddle for the same [Jsfiddle Input Focus](http://jsfiddle.net/gwd1fLxk/2/)

Comment: thanks, it worked well :) took me 1 min only to apply for my angular directive, +1

Answer (score 0):

In your form element put autocomplete attribute like below

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```